# Draw a graphical UML diagram from .uml files of Eclipse UML2

Tags: eclipse, uml

I have created MyExample.uml file through Eclipse UML2 package.
(I followed http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT/UML2/Getting_Started_with_UML2 )

Then I got the XMI file defining UML components and relations.

Then, how can I draw a graphical UML diagram from this XMI automatically?

[image: MyExample.uml]

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this so can't confirm it works.  It is documented however.

1. Install [Papyrus](http://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/).
2. Follow [these instructions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Papyrus_User_Guide#Create_a_diagram_from_an_existing_uml_file) to generate a diagram.

Like you I suspect, I assumed the standard Eclipse Modelling Tools would include graphical editors.  If they do I didn't find them.  By installing Papyrus I was able to create uml diagrams manually; hopefully you can generate one too.

If you try this, it would be good to know if it works.  Again apologies for not testing before posting, I don't have access to a suitable environment at the moment.

hth.